# React useState stuck after setting localStorage as initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a shopping cart with React Hooks that saves in the local storage and gets retrieved when reloading the browser.

Everything pretty much works the way I want it to, but after I reload the browser and retrieve the localStorage-data, the item state won't update anymore. The cart object looks identical before and after reloading.

My cart context provider looks like this:

```
  const { itemList } = useContext(ItemContext)

  const [cart, setCart] = useState(() => {
    const localData =
      localStorage.getItem('cart');
    return localData !== null
      ? JSON.parse(localData)
      : [];
  });

  console.log(cart)

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
  }, [cart] )

  const addItem = id => {
    let addedItem = itemList.find(item => item.id === id)
    let addedItemExists = cart.find(item => item.id === id)
    if (addedItemExists) {
      addedItem.quantity += 1
      setCart([...cart]);
    } else {
      addedItem.quantity = 1
      setCart([...cart, addedItem]);
    }
  };
```

(the `itemList` is a dummy data list with three items)

I've also tried to fix this by using a reducer, but I got the same result.

I've only been using React and JS for a couple of weeks, so I'm sorry if this is a noobie-question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to update your state partially, you need to use `setState`'s first argument, representing the previous state

```js
setCart((prev) => ([...prev]));
...
setCart((prev) => ([...prev, addedItems]));
```

instead of using its current value.

Now, your `addItem` function looks buggy in case `addedItemExists` is `true`, you don't seem to update the local state but rather `itemList` (you just update `cart` with its current value).

Maybe you should try the following :

```js
const addItem = (id) => {
  const addedItem = itemList.find(item => item.id === id);
  const addedItemExists = cart.some(item => item.id === id);
  if (addedItemExists) {
    setCart((prev) => prev.map((item) => (
      item.id === id
        ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
        : item
    )));
  } else {
    setCart((prev) => ([ ...prev, { ...addedItem, quantity: 1 } ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: The tweak to the `addedItemExists` seemed to do the trick. If I had 'Item 1' in the cart, I could add 'Item 2' and 'Item 3', but the quantity was stuck. Could you elaborate on updating the state in this way?

Comment: In my example, if `addedItemExists` is true, I map the cart items to only update the quantity of the one that has the same id as the added item.
If false, I just add the added item to the cart, with a quantity of 1. If I understand correctly, this does not work for you ?

Comment: I just updated my answer, I forgot a `}` at the end of `setCart` in `else` statement.

Comment: Your initial answer worked, just a poorly formatted response on my end. My original problem was that I could add unique items, but not increase the quantity.
It works like a charm now, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this instead the way you do

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    const localData =
      localStorage.getItem('cart');
    return localData !== null
      ? JSON.parse(localData)
      : [];
  }, [] )
```

Answer (score 0):

so, you are setting cart initially. (in the useState). Try doing it in the useEffect. this is just for clean code. I made a change in the if-else part.

```js
  const { itemList } = useContext(ItemContext)

  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem('cart');
    setCart(localData && localData.length > 0 ? JSON.parse(localData): []);
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
  }, [cart] )

  const addItem = id => {
    let addedItem = itemList.find(item => item.id === id)
    let addedItemExists = cart.find(item => item.id === id)
    if (addedItemExists) {
      addedItem.quantity += 1
      setCart(cart => [...cart]);
    } else {
      addedItem.quantity = 1
      setCart(cart => [...cart, addedItem]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: This is what i'm doing right now, but the problem using useEffect with [ ] to set the initial value only once on first, causes a slightly delay. like the page gets loaded and then the initial value gets updated. Is there any way to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

try this instead:

```
const [cart, setCard] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localData)))
```

or you could try:

```
const [cart, setCard] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localData) : []))
```

then use:

```
cart && cart.map
```

when you want to map over it as `cart` will be `null` if doesn't exist in `localStorage`

Answer (score -1):

You are just passing a function inside `useState` **without** calling it

Just call the function.

```js
const { itemList } = useContext(ItemContext);

const initialStateFun = () => {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    return localData !== null ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
  }
const [cart, setCart] = useState(initialStateFun()); //<--- call the fun

console.log(cart);

...
```

Also, if you want to go even simpler then just use ternary

```js
useState(localStorage.getItem('cart') !== null ? JSON.parse(localData) : []);
```

Comment: You can pass a function to `useState`, that is valid. It will call it.